# php array into javascript array looks different

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is what it shows when i use php array and encode it into js.
It shows everything on a different line.

php array  `$test_var = array('11', '222', '3333', '44444');`

But console shows js array as it should look like

`console.log('<?php echo json_encode($test_var); ?>');`

`["11","222","3333","44444"]`

[image: php array img]

This is what i have in js

`var jsvar = '<?php echo json_encode($test_var); ?>';`

If i just do that in js it works like it should

`var jsvar = ["11","222","3333","44444"];`

[image: js array img]

Comment: Where are those images from? What does *It shows everything on a different line.* mean in this context?

Comment: this is the array i have `["11","222","3333","44444"]` when it is in php array it shows 222 as 
2
2
2
not as 222

Answer (score 5):

You are wrapping the json output in quotes. This causes JS to interpret it as string not array

Change to

```
var jsvar = <?php echo json_encode($test_var); ?>;
```